# checkbox checking verification

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

HTML:

```
<div>
    <input>
    <label>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('div input').live('click',function(){
    alert($(this).is(':checked'));
});
$('div').live('click,'function(e){
    if(!$(e.target).is('input'))
        $(this).find('input').click();
});
```

Whenever I click on the input it accurately displays what the input turns into (if I turn on the input it alerts true)
But whenever I click on the div/label it does the opposite (when the input turns on it alerts false)

Is there a way to test whether the input is being turned on and off in both circumstances instead of 1?

[I assume that the reason this is happening because one is triggered by the browser which happens before jquery (even though I assumed jquery should happen first, but whatever) and in the other case the jquery is running before the trigger of the 'checked', but can't seem to figure out how to either delay the trigger until after the script, or force it to run before the script.]
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? If your intention is to have a click on the label check or uncheck the checkbox that will happen automatically if you have `<label for="idofinputhere">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can monitor `change()` on the checkbox itself, then on DIV click you can change the value in the checkbox directly and then trigger `change()` instead of `click()`.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').live('change',function(){
    alert($(this).is(':checked'));
});

$('div').live('click',function(e){
    if(!$(e.target).is('input')) {
        var $input = $(this).find('input');
        $input.prop("checked", !$input.is(':checked')).change();
    }
});
```

Also, if your purpose is to avoid the whole `<label for="" />` annoyance, check this out.

```
<label><input type="checkbox" value="awesome" /> Check it</label>
```

Comment: This ends up working (ish). I had to change it from .prop to .attr as my version of jquery doesn't support .prop method. Nice idea with using change vs. click.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$('div input').live('click',function(){
    alert($(this).is(':checked'));
});
$('div').live('click,'function(e){
    if(!$(e.target).is('input'))
        $(this).find('input').triggerHandler("click");
});
```

Comment: `jQuery.triggerHandler()` won't work in conjunction with `jQuery.live()` because live observes the event on the document, not the element in question, and `triggerHandler()` doesn't cause bubbling. You'd also have to extend your answer to perform the update to the checkbox prior to triggering the handlers, as it's the browser's default behavior that you're skipping and it's the browser that updates the checkbox value.

Comment: I just tried this and as Mike said, it doesn't work unfortunately.